# Prevent parent animation to child in CSS

Tags: html, css

```css
nav {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 8rem;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.nav-list {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.nav-list li {
  line-height: 8rem;
  position: relative;
}

.sub-menu li {
  color: #c40707;
  line-height: 7rem;
}

.nav-list a {
  display: block;
  color: black;
  padding: 0 1.5rem;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: color 300ms;
}

.nav-list a::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #ff2a00;
  height: 3px;
  width: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 15px;
  transition: 0s;
}

.nav-list a:hover::after {
  width: 100%;
}

.nav-list a:hover {
  color: #e3dedd;
}

.sub-menu a {
  color: #7e7978;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: 200;
}

.sub-menu {
  width: 20rem;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
  z-index: 500;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  top: 2rem;
}

.nav-list li:hover>.sub-menu {
  top: 7.5rem;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <ul class="nav-list">
        <li>
            <a href="%">Men</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li><a href="#">shirts</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Shorts</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Tracks</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Shoes</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</header>
```

Im trying to create a dropdown using CSS. I created a nav bar with certain elements that are mentioned in the code. I applied a hover effect to the nav bar. I created a dropdown using  `.nav-list li: hover > .sub-menu` as the command. However, the hover effect I had for the nav bar is being applied to the sub menu too. How to prevent this from happening?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please edit your snippet to add your HTML and move your CSS to the CSS box.

Comment: The HTML is incomplete. To help, edit the snippet to fix the HTML errors. We'll be able to help you much better.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. I didnt understand your suggestion completely, can you let me know what more information is needed? I'll reiterate the problem once again. As shown in the snippet, "MENS" is contained in the "nav bar" and the remaining elements are part of "sub-menu" class.  Nav bar has a hover effect of bottom padding. But this is being applied to child class to (sub-menu). How do I prevent this>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you need to be more specific in your CSS selectors. Since you only want the `hover` to affect the "Men" top level parent element, you need to use the direct descendent `>` selector **after** your `.nav-list` selector - since you only want the top level `li a`.

I changed your CSS in this part:

```
.nav-list > li > a {
  display: block;
  color: black;
  padding: 0 1.5rem;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: color 300ms;
}

.nav-list > li > a::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #ff2a00;
  height: 3px;
  width: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 15px;
  transition: 0s;
}

.nav-list > li > a:hover::after {
  width: 100%;
}
```

That ensures that **only** the top level direct children elements `li` and `a` are selected.

```css
nav {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 8rem;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.nav-list {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.nav-list li {
  line-height: 8rem;
  position: relative;
}

.sub-menu li {
  color: #c40707;
  line-height: 7rem;
}

.nav-list > li > a {
  display: block;
  color: black;
  padding: 0 1.5rem;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: color 300ms;
}

.nav-list > li > a::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #ff2a00;
  height: 3px;
  width: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 15px;
  transition: 0s;
}

.nav-list > li > a:hover::after {
  width: 100%;
}

.nav-list a:hover {
  color: #e3dedd;
}

.sub-menu a {
  color: #7e7978;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: 200;
}

.sub-menu {
  width: 20rem;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
  z-index: 500;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  top: 2rem;
}

.nav-list li:hover > .sub-menu {
  top: 7.5rem;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <ul class="nav-list">
        <li>
            <a href="%">Men</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li><a href="#">shirts</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Shorts</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Tracks</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Shoes</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</header>
```

Comment: hey, thanks for the suggestion. It'll be really helpful if you can help me with another thing. The dropdown has a white background but behind that, there's an image. Can you let me know how I can blur the image when the dropdown is used? I'm using backdrop-filter: blur(2px) saturate(180%); in sub-menu li but that doesn't do the work. Thanks again!

Comment: You'll need JS to do this and is beyond the scope of the original question. If this does answer your question, please upvote/mark as the accepted answer. Then you can use this working code in a new question about the image blur.

Answer (score 0):

Add the class "main-menu-item"

`<a class="main-menu-item" href="%">Men</a>`

In the CSS Code, change your hover and after effect from "a" to this:

```
.nav-list .main-menu-item::after {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        background-color: #ff2a00;
        height: 3px;
        width: 0;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 15px;
        transition: 0s;
    }

.nav-list .main-menu-item:hover {
        color: #e3dedd;
    }
```

**Here is the running example:**

```css
    nav {
        display: inline-flex;
        align-items: center;
        width: 100%;
        height: 8rem;
        border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    }

    .nav-list {
        display: flex;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .nav-list li {
        line-height: 8rem;
        position: relative;
    }

    .sub-menu li {
        color: #c40707;
        line-height: 7rem;
    }

    .nav-list a {
        display: block;
        color: black;
        padding: 0 1.5rem;
        font-size: 1.4rem;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        transition: color 300ms;
    }

    .nav-list .main-menu-item::after {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        background-color: #ff2a00;
        height: 3px;
        width: 0;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 15px;
        transition: 0s;
    }

    .nav-list a:hover::after {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .nav-list .main-menu-item:hover {
        color: #e3dedd;
    }

    .sub-menu a {
        color: #7e7978;
        font-size: 1.5rem;
        font-weight: 200;
    }

    .sub-menu {
        width: 20rem;
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        visibility: hidden;
        z-index: 500;
        background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
        box-sizing: border-box;
        top: 2rem;
    }

    .nav-list li:hover>.sub-menu {
        top: 7.5rem;
        opacity: 1;
        visibility: visible;
    }
```

```html
<header>
    <div class="container">
        <nav>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav-list">
        <li>
            <a class="main-menu-item" href="%">Men</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">shirts</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Shorts</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Tracks</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Shoes</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</header>
```